# RethinkDB r.DBList() gives blank object in return

Tags: go, rethinkdb

I'm using this golang code to check list of databases in RethinkDB, and getting no lists in return.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    r "gopkg.in/rethinkdb/rethinkdb-go.v6"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(0)

    rdbOpts := r.ConnectOpts{
        Address: "localhost:28015",
    }

    rconn, err := r.Connect(rdbOpts)
    checkError(err)

    res, err := r.DBList().Run(rconn)
    checkError(err)
    printObj(res)
}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
}

func printObj(v interface{}) {
    vBytes, _ := json.Marshal(v)
    fmt.Println(string(vBytes))
}
```

Result:

```
$ go run main.go
{}
```

This is just a fresh started Rethinkdb instance on local machine, which if queried through Data Explorer from web ui indeed returns the following answer for query `r.dbList()`

```json
[

    "rethinkdb" ,
    "test"

]
```

What am I doing wrong in my query? I know it must be something small, as it's just basic query.

Appreciate any pointers or help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see what I was doing wrong. ‍♂️

I didn't process the response to show rows data as per RethinkDb docs.

Here's the working `main()` func code:

```golang
func main() {

    rdbOpts := r.ConnectOpts{
        Address: "localhost:28015",
    }

    rconn, err := r.Connect(rdbOpts)
    checkError(err)

    res, err := r.DBList().Run(rconn)
    checkError(err)
    printObj(res)

    var row []interface{}
    err2 := res.All(&row)
    if err2 == r.ErrEmptyResult {
        // row not found
    }
    if err2 != nil {
        // error
    }

    if row != nil {
        jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(row)
        fmt.Println("total number of rows:", len(row))
        fmt.Println("row map obj:", row)
        fmt.Println("row JSON output:", string(jsonData))
    } else {
        fmt.Println("No rows returned")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run main.go
{}
total number of rows: 2
row map obj: [rethinkdb test]
row JSON output: ["rethinkdb","test"]
```